# Dependency management in iOS

Tags: ios, dependency-management

I have the following scenario:

I'm developing an iOS application that is being used for different companies.
For each company, there are a few differences:

- App Icon
- Theme Color
- Images (e.g., company logo)
- Strings (e.g., company name)

The best approach is to make a single code and then, override some values and assets for each one of the applications.
In Android I can easily achieve this by creating a library module (with the core of the app) and an application module for each company (with no Java code) just by overriding the resources.

I'm trying to develop the same structure at XCode, but the way of doing it is not clear for me.
After a brief research, I considered some options: Framework, Static Library and Subprojects.

Which one would be the correct way of doing it? Should I consider using a Dependency/Package Manager (like Swift Package Manager, CocoaPods or Carthage)?

These package manager are git-dependent? Because I'm working with SVN, and switching to Git is not viable at this point.

Project settings:
XCode 9
Swift 4

Comment: If you have total control of the project, another option would be a single workspace/project with multiple targets. This way you will have a common codebase with different (per target) assets & settings.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is, yes, use **one project** with **variations**.   (Note that things like Swift Package Manager, CocoaPods, Carthage are irrelevant here.)  There are a number of ways to achieve that - the other folks have given many excellent pointers.

Comment: (Just BTW never, ever use cocoa pods.  Carthage is great.)

Comment: One thing is, recall that storyboards are very inherent in iOS development.

Indeed, you'll be pleased to hear that Xcode/iOS **inherently includes the idea of "alternate storyboards" for a given class/screen**.

(For example - quite simply, you may (if you wish) do that for iPhone versus iPad.)
Depending on your exact needs, this may be useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use targets.

Let me show you how I handle this hierarchy with my `assets` / `settings`.

### Assets

---

My `Assets` directory

[image: Assets directory]

- **Common folder** contains the common `images`
- **Company1 folder** contains the `images` / `colors` / `certificates`

You have to change the `Target Membership` for the `Company1 > Images` by selecting only the target that it does need to refer to.

[image: Target settings]

For example, `common > Assets` needs to refer to all `targets`.

### Code

---

You can do the same with your code if you need to do something different in each targets.

Personally, I use the power of `extension` to split the code in different source files to be able to refer to different targets.

Refer this file to the `Company1` target

```
extension FirstViewController {

    func doSomething() {
        // implement this method for the company 1
    }

}
```

Refer this file to the `Company2` target

```
extension FirstViewController {

    func doSomething() {
        // implement this method for the company 2
    }

}
```

Refer this file to all `targets`

```
class LandingEmptyViewController {

    func foobar() {
        self.doSomething()
    }

}
```

You can also pass some `flags` per target in the `Build Settings`

Using those solutions, you will be able to do the same of in Android.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with **Static Framework** for developing this kind of projects. Now, Static framework has its own ups and downs.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

- Create a Core Module Framework for all the common classes that will be shared for different Apps as Company1Extenssion, Company2Extenssion.
- Now include this Core module framework into the individual projects by creating respective workspaces.
- The individual extended projects will hold their own Assets, App Icons, App Name.
- Note, one of the cons of this approach is you can't include pods in it. You have to go for Carthage or Git sub modules for any Third party library.
- One of the Pros of this approach is you can maintain Code security for the core module by specifying the functions or classes to be extended to the Extensions.

**Note:** During release of the app don't forget to ensure the proper payload structure of the ipa file.